# Counting number of elements divisible by 4 in an array using MIPS

Tags: arrays, assembly, count, mips

enter code here   I'm trying to count the number of elements in this array that are divisible by four, currently it prints out the number of times the program loops. For some reason the program calls mod every time. Can anyone identify why this might be happening?

```
.data
arr: .word 5, 4, 8,12, 13, 16, 18, 20, 24,23,0
msg: .asciiz "Elements Divisible By 4 :   "
four: .word 4
.text
lb $s4, four
.globl main

main:

addi $t0, $0, 0 # clear i
addi $t1, $0, 0 # clear sum
ori $t2, $0, 11 # Initializing t2 to its constant value 10
la $t3, arr # load address of array into t3

loop:

slt $t4, $t0, $t2 # compare, $t4 = i < sum ? 1 : 0
beq $t4, $0, end # if i is not < 11, exit the loop
lw $t4, 0($t3) # load current array element into t4

andi $t4, $t4, 3
beq $t4, $zero, mod
j loop



mod: # if-else exit 

add $t1, $t1, 1 # add it to sum
add $t0, $t0, 1 # increment i
add $t3, $t3, 4 # increment current array element pointer
j loop

end:

addi $v0, $0, 4 # Now we print out result: string
la $a0, msg
syscall

addi $v0, $0, 1 # followed by the actual sum (which is in t1)
add $a0, $t1, $0
la $t5, exit     
syscall

exit:
 j exit
```

Working version

```
.data
arr: .word 12, 4, 8, 12, 13, 16, 18, 20, 24, 23, 0
msg: .asciiz "Counter  "
fourMod: .word 4

.text

lb $s1, fourMod

.globl main

main:

addi $t0, $0, 0 # clear i
addi $t1, $0, 0 # clear sum
ori $t2, $0, 10 # Initializing t2 to its constant value 10
la $t3, arr # load address of array into t3

loop:
slt $t4, $t0, $t2 # compare, $t4 = i < sum ? 1 : 0
beq $t4, $0, end # if i is not < 10, exit the loop
lw $t4, 0($t3) # load current array element into t4

andi $t4, $t4, 3
beq $t4, $zero, mod

add $t0, $t0, 1 # increment i
add $t3, $t3, 4 # increment current array element pointer
j loop

mod: 
#add to the divisible by 4 counter?
add $s2, $s2, 1
add $t0, $t0, 1 # increment i
add $t3, $t3, 4 # increment current array element pointer
j loop


end:

addi $v0, $0, 4 # Now we print out result: string
la $a0, msg
syscall

addi $v0, $0, 1 # followed by the actual sum (which is in t1)
add $a0, $s2, $0
la $t5, exit     
syscall

exit:
 j exit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never tell your program not to execute the code after `mod:`:

```
add $t3, $t3, 4 # increment current array element pointer
    <--- There's nothing here to prevent the execution to continue with the below add
mod:
add $s2, $s2, 1
```

Use a branch instruction if you want to skip over some code. Or in your case what you want is probably a `j loop`.

---

Another thing is that you're doing an unnecessary division, which often is a relatively slow operation. Checking whether an integer is a multiple of four can be done by testing the two least significant bits:

```
andi $t4, $t4, 3      # Isolate the two least significant bits
beq $t4, $zero, mod   # We've got a multiple of 4 if those two bits are zero
```

---

**Edit:** With your updated code you're still incrementing your "is divisible" counter on every iteration. It would probably be best if you inverted your branch condition and changed that part of the code into:

```
andi $t4, $t4, 3
bne $t4, $zero, not_divisible
add $t1, $t1, 1 # add it to sum

not_divisible: # if-else exit 

add $t0, $t0, 1 # increment i
....  # omitted for brevity
```

Comment: For some reason when I add j loop where you say to the program doesn't ever go to mod, also never goes to end, it just loops forever inside loop.  Also updated my code to what I have now.

Comment: I actually realized it was working fine after your soultions but I wasn't incrementing when it went to mod.

Comment: I'm actually trying to convert the answer thats output from this into binary and then count the 1's in that binary sequence but I seem to be having a similar problem where it just outputs whatevers in li $v0 1 maybe you could take a look at that real quick too before I post another question. I've put it as a secondary question at the top.

Comment: A question should be a single question. If you have new question, post it as a separate question (and mention this one as a reference if necessary).